# How to (or should I) monitor or ensure running of a monitoring software?

Tags: monitoring, monit, god

I'm writing a system/service monitoring software, and my primary goal is to make it as failsafe as possible.

Right now, I have a binary script which starts the master process, which forks off children which do the actual monitoring and reporting. The master only manages the restarting of children if they fail, and some communication between the children.

Given this level of failsafe, is it advisable to add another layer of monitoring for the master process?

Supposing my code is in a high level language (python et al.), would it make sense to wrap my software in a initscript or shellscript which watches it, or would it be redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reminds me of this old worm that would consist of 2 processes. If one of the processes was killed, the other one would respawn it and vice versa.

If this software is supposed to run on linux you can simply use `/etc/inittab` with the `respawn` option.

Comment: I am aiming for Windows as well. And besides, that worm would have been hideously difficult to code, since in Linux only a parent process can restart a child.